# Rotate WPF control or change screen orientation

Tags: wpf, user-controls, rotation, window, orientation

I have wpf project with one Window (MainWindow). Depending upon the config file it shows one of two UserControl's as Content. It may be a horizontal (1920x1080) control or vertical (1080x1920) control. It's fine with horizontal screen, but when vertical is loaded I would like to do:

1) rotate window/control by 270 degrees
2) change primary screen orientation

I would prefer to just rotate application and don't interact with windows API. I can't change orientation manually, because I have only remote access to this computer.

Answer (score 1):

You can not rotate the Window object itself, as it is positioned by the window management system built in Windows. You can, however, transform (and thus rotate) any [FrameworkElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement(v=vs.110).aspx) inside the window. This includes, but is not limited to, the `Grid`, the `Button` and the `TextBox` elements.

All you need to do is edit the `LayoutTransform` property on the element you want to rotate, which is most likely the root element in your window. Set the rotation to 270/-90 degrees and WPF will automatically rotate your UI.

Because you are using the `LayoutTransform` property, the layout system will also scale you UI correctly.  The `RenderTransform` property causes the control to first be rendered, then be rotated.

Comment: LayoutTransform is exactly what I wanted. I tried RenderTransform before and it was little moved and resized. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

YES WE CAN CHANGE SCCREEN ORIENTATION  USING
`DEVMODE  &  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;`

its bit late to reply but I am replaying for the new ones , if someone com across this article for change screen rotation in C# or VB .

Please use the link given below to get help Mr. Hannes Completely write an article to change screen rotation and luckily its working fine for me (Windows 11) as now of..

https://www.codeguru.com/dotnet/creating-a-screen-rotator-in-net/